# Duplicate UUID's for Physical Volumes But PV's aren't in a Volume Group

Tags: linux, lvm

I have some dead/stale/non existent logical volumes without group

pvs said

```
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[306492]) leaked on pvs invocation. Parent PID 30844: -su
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster3p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster1p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos3p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster2p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos3p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-nfs2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos2p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware3p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap1p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-samba1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware2p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster4p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-nfs2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-samba1p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-recovero2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap2p2
  PV                                            VG    Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree   
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster4p2            lvm2 a--    29,51g   29,51g
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-nas2p1p1              lvm2 a--    10,00g   10,00g
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-recovero2             lvm2 a--    32,91g   32,91g
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware4--1p1       lvm2 a--    33,00g   33,00g
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware4--2p1       lvm2 a--  1000,00g 1000,00g
  /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware4p2          lvm2 a--     4,00t    4,00t
  /dev/md127                                    disco lvm2 a--     8,19t    2,56t
```

The only active is disco with md127,why the other nas2p1p1,etc are still alive?
How to delete it forever?
I did lvremove and vgremove for old vg groups

vgs said

```
      Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster3p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster1p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos3p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster2p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos3p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-nfs2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-centos2p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware3p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap1p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-samba1p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackware2p2
  Found duplicate PV sun9LI9sXDLI2YPuMINH3xVos86c97eu: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-cluster4p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-nfs2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap2p2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-samba1p2
  Found duplicate PV 8M3D5lq37NOiKJ60lwxnS3fK40ybvl2S: using /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-recovero2 not /dev/disk/by-id/dm-name-disco-slackldap2p2
  VG    #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  disco   1  19   0 wz--n- 8,19t 2,56t
```

How to solve?
Thanks

Comment: We don't have the complete story here. Somehow the storage configuration has changed to where it's now finding multiple versions of several PV's. I think we need to know what happened immediately before this point so we can give responsible advice.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that you should be able to do a `ls -l /dev/disk/by-path` to try to figure out where these other PV's are coming from. You can use `pvremove` which will destroy the LVM header on the block device (so that it stops showing up as a duplicate PV) but since that could result in catasrophic data loss, I would want to know where these PV's are coming from before saying you should do that. This might be a multipath setup and you just need to set up filtering so LVM doesn't hit the individual devices for the various paths.

Comment: i don't have path

Comment: What Linux distribution are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. I was using `kpartx` for backups a few months ago and forgot to close the devices with `kpartx -d`.
I discover using partprobe that the lvm volumes wich belong to virtual machines are "exported" to to the server,and fill /dev/mapper with duplicates lvms,so i used kpartx -d
to all devices in /dev/mapper and situation return ok.
lvs,pvs,vgs didn't give any error message now.